# Flaoating Action button position

Tags: android, position, floating-action-button

I tried adding the floating action button but just not able to get it to position in the expected place.I've the xml along with the obtained and expected image.

Actually I want two such floating action buttons one on top of the other.

**MapsActivity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/maplinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context="com.example.srinivas.democomplete.MapsActivity" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303F9F"
                android:text="Auto Complete"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bsolarpanel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303F9F"
                android:text="Add solar panels"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Current button position]
[image: Expected position]

Any help would be great thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the line

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
```

You can use `margin` to set it according to your need

**UPDATE**

You can add some more attributes like

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Comment: removing and adding margins didn't work either, it remains in the same position

Comment: Layout you posted is fine, I've tested it and it's ok. You can add some more attributes like `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"`

Comment: It's good to hear. If it helped you, it's nice gesture to accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: Yea it all worked out now.. just change it as `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`. That's what I've asked!